# How do I see request headers on Android WebView requests?

Tags: android, webview

How can I intercept all requests made out of an Android `WebView` and get the corresponding request headers? I want to see the headers for every request made from my `WebView` including XHRs, script sources, css, etc.

The equivalent on iOS is to override `NSURLCache` which will give you all this information. The following are probably the closest to what I want but as far as I can see `WebViewClient` only ever gives us back strings:

```
void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url);
WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url);
```

Comment: Reading the request headers is not possible with Android's `WebView` or `WebViewClient`, afaik. I solved this problem using a lightweight proxy.

Comment: @acj - did you do a proxy programmatically on the `WebView` or external (router/network level)?

Comment: I configure it in Mobile Networks in the device settings. Another option: If I just need a quick-and-dirty method to check the headers, I'll start an instance of netcat (`nc`) on my laptop and connect the `WebView` to the netcat instance.

Comment: If I understood correctly neither of these solutions is suitable for production deployment if I need to get these headers during the regular runs for users, right?

Comment: Correct. For regular runs, it's possible to configure a proxy programmatically using reflection ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488338/webview-android-proxy)), but any such approach will be fragile and unsupported.

Comment: Actual answer should be that starting from Android 5.0 one can use new API method `WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)`, where the `request` parameter provides the required info.

Comment: Chuck is a simple in-app HTTP inspector for Android OkHttp clients.

Answer (score 19):

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                Log.d("", "request.getRequestHeaders()::"+request.getRequestHeaders());

                return null;
            }
        });
```

Comment: This was never firing on my code. I tried `Anton Prokopov`'s suggestion below and that successfully printed the headers.

Answer (score 3):

You question sounds very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847576/how-to-view-debug-non-standard-request-headers-my-phones-browser-is-sending), so the immediate and unequivocal answer is that **it is not possible to read the request headers on Android's WebView or WebViewClient**.

There are workarounds, however, that could allow you get what you need. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18044381/2946787) describes in more detail how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

I also had some problems with intercepting request headers in `WebView myWebView`.

First I tryed to do this with setting custom `WebViewClient` for `myWebView`.

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                Log.v("USERAGENTBROWSE", "shouldOverrideUrlLoading api >= 21 called");

                //some code

                return true;
            }

    @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.v("USERAGENTBROWSE", "shouldOverrideUrlLoading api < 21 called");

                //some code

                return true;
            }

});
```

But method `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(...)` was never called. And I have really no ideas why.

Then I found that there is the way to intercept some common headers like `"User-Agent"`, `"Cache-Control"`, etc.:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("your_custom_user_agent_header");
myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(int mode);
...
```

Hope it may help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

By [this way](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) you can enable debugging for web view application and using Chrome Developer Tools to see full details of your requests, responses, css, javascripts, etc

Comment: Remote debugging is for debugging Chrome on a remote device, doesn't work with WebViews

Comment: @JohnSardinha It works with WebView.