# Get request headers at webview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview

I login by webview and I need to get headers after logging in.
I found, that i can get it by using a method "**WebResourceRequest.requestHeaders**":

```
 override fun shouldInterceptRequest(
                view: WebView?,
                request: WebResourceRequest?
            ): WebResourceResponse? {
                request.requestHeaders // this method
                return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request)
            }
```

but it allows only for >=21 api version. My application has 16 minversion, are there any other ways to get headers from webview request?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610790/add-custom-headers-to-webview-resource-requests-android

Comment: and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19692617/how-do-i-see-request-headers-on-android-webview-requests

Comment: @Droidman, i want to get already existing headers instead of add

Answer (score 1):

You haven't clearly described your problem. I assume you want to change `minimum api` of your application in order to use method "WebResourceRequest.requestHeaders".
For this you can do this:

1. Right click on your project file
2. Select "Open Module Settings"
3. Go to the "Flavors" tab.

[image]

4. Select the "Min Sdk Version" from the drop down list

For further help you can refer to this post. [Changing API level Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465049/changing-api-level-android-studio/27626671#27626671)